# Python: AttributeError: "'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'tanh'"

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have seen couple of questions with similar title, however I am afraid, none of them could satisfactorily answer my question and that is, how do I take tan inverse or lets say exp of a numpy ndarray? For instance, piece of my code looks similar to this-

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray,zeros,array,dot,exp
import itertools

def zetta_G(x,spr_g,theta_g,c_g):
#this function computes estimated g:

    #c_g is basically a matrix of dim equal to g and whose elements contains list of centers that describe the fuzzy system for each element of g:
    m,n=c_g.shape[0],c_g.shape[1]
    #creating an empty matrix of dim mxn to hold regressors:
    zetta_g=zeros((m,n),dtype=ndarray)
    #creating an empty matrix of dim mxn to hold estimated g:
    z_g=np.zeros((m,n),dtype=ndarray)
    #for filling rows
    for k in range(m):
        #for filling columns
        for p in range(n):
            #container to hold-length being equal to number of inputs(e1,e2,e3 etc)
            Mu=[[] for i in range(len(x))]
            for i in range(len(x)):
            #filling that with number of zeros equal to len of center
                Mu[i]=np.zeros(len(c_g[k][p]))
            #creating an empty list for holding rules
            M=[]
            #piece of code for creating rules-all possible combinations
            for i in range(len(x)):
                for j in range(len(c_g[k][p])):
                    Mu[i][j]=exp(-.5*((x[i]-c_g[k][p][j])/spr_g[k][p])**2)

            b=list(itertools.product(*Mu))
            for i in range(len(b)):
                M.append(reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,b[i]))

            M=np.array(M)
            S=np.sum(M)
            #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
            zetta_g[k][p]=M/S
            z_g[k][p]=dot(M/S,theta_g[k][p])
    return zetta_g,z_g

if __name__=='__main__':
    x=[1.2,.2,.4]
    cg11,cg12,cg13,cg21,cg22,cg23,cg31,cg32,cg33=[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10],[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10],[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10],[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10],[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10],[-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12],[-6.5,-4.5,-2.5,0,2.5,4.5,6.5],[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5],[-3.5,-2.5,-1.5,0,1.5,2.5,3.5]
    C,spr_f=array([[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10],[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10],[-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10]]),[2.2,2,2.1]
    c_g=array([[cg11,cg12,cg13],[cg21,cg22,cg23],[cg31,cg32,cg33]])
    spr_g=array([[2,2.1,2],[2.1,2.2,3],[2.5,1,1.5]])
    theta_g=np.zeros((c_g.shape[0],c_g.shape[1]),dtype=ndarray)
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    N=0
    for i in range(c_g.shape[0]):
        for j in range(c_g.shape[1]):
            length=len(c_g[i][j])**len(x)
            theta_g[i][j]=np.random.sample(length)
            N=N+(len(c_g[i][j]))**len(x)
    zetta_g,z_g=zetta_G(x,spr_g,theta_g,c_g)
    #zetta is a function that accepts following args-- x: which is a list of certain dim, spr_g: is a matrix of dimension similar to theta_g and c_g. theta_g and c_g are numpy matrices with lists as individual elements
    print(zetta_g)
    print(z_g)
    inv=np.tanh(z_g)
    print(inv)
```

Comment: _"...I need to assign entire list to each elements of my numpy matrix(array)"_ This is not possible. Please show what you want to achieve and we can show what is the best way to get there. It is definitely not the way you are trying to do.

Comment: @AGNGazer
I have edited my post, kindly have a look. The problem is in functions zetta_F, zetta_G and in f() wherein I seek to fill an empty matrix of 3x3 dim with arrays and lists. It is the requirement.

Comment: I think all your code is too large and not informative. You should provide a minimal example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer, specifically `a[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]` - is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi @AGNGazer, I have edited my code to provide a minimal example. Kindly have a look again.

Comment: Your mininal example doesn't get past `random.sample(range(2),9*1331)`

Comment: @hpaulj, Hi! Just a sec, I will modify it

Comment: @hpaulj,
I have updated the minimal working example and it is working fine. Hope it helps to solve my problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [89]: a=np.array([[1],[3],[2]],dtype=np.ndarray)
In [90]: a
Out[90]: 
array([[1],
       [3],
       [2]], dtype=object)
```

Note that the `dtype` is `object`, not `ndarray`.  If the `dtype` isn't one of the recognized numeric or string types, it is `object`, a generic pointer, just like the elements of a list.

```
In [91]: np.tanh(a)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tanh'
```

`np.tanh` is trying to delegate the task to the elements of array.  Commonly math on object dtype arrays is performed by list like iteration on the elements.  It does not do the fast compiled numeric numpy math.

If `a` is ordinary number array:

```
In [95]: np.tanh(np.array([[1],[3],[2]]))
Out[95]: 
array([[0.76159416],
       [0.99505475],
       [0.96402758]])
```

With `object` dtype arrays, your ability to do numeric calculations is limited.  Some things work, others don't.  It's hit-or-miss.

---

Here's a first stab at cleaning up your code; it's not tested.

```
def zetta_G(x,spr_g,theta_g,c_g):
    m,n=c_g.shape[0],c_g.shape[1]
    #creating an empty matrix of dim mxn to hold regressors:
    zetta_g=zeros((m,n),dtype=object)
    #creating an empty matrix of dim mxn to hold estimated g:
    z_g=np.zeros((m,n),dtype=object)
    #for filling rows
    for k in range(m):
        #for filling columns
        for p in range(n):
            #container to hold-length being equal to number of inputs(e1,e2,e3 etc)

            Mu = np.zeros((len(x), len(c_g[k,p])))
            #creating an empty list for holding rules

            for i in range(len(x)):
                Mu[i,:]=exp(-.5*((x[i]-c_g[k,p,:])/spr_g[k,p])**2)
                # probably can calc Mu without any loop

            M = []
            b=list(itertools.product(*Mu))
            for i in range(len(b)):
                M.append(reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,b[i]))

            M=np.array(M)
            S=np.sum(M)

            zetta_g[k,p]=M/S
            z_g[k,p]=dot(M/S,theta_g[k,p])
    return zetta_g,z_g
```

---

Running your code, and adding some `.shape` displays I see that

`z_g` is (3,3) and contains just single numbers.  So it can be initialed as a plain 2d float array:

```
z_g=np.zeros((m,n))
```

`theta_g` is (3,3), but with variable length array elements

```
print([i.shape for i in theta_g.flat])
[(1331,), (1331,), (1331,), (1331,), (1331,), (729,), (343,), (1331,), (343,)]
```

`zetta_g` matches in shapes

If I change:

```
x=np.array([1.2,.2,.4])
```

I can calculate `Mu` without a loop with:

```
Mu = exp(-.5*((x[:,None]-np.array(c_g[k,p])[None,:])/spr_g[k,p])**2)
```

`c_g` is a (3,3) array with variable length lists; I can vectorize the

```
((x[i]-c_g[k,p][j])
```

expression with:

```
x[:,None]-np.array(c_g[k,p])[None,:]
```

Not a big time saver here since `x` has 4 elements and `c_g` elements are only 7-11 long.  But cleaner.

In this running code I don't see a `tanh`, so I don't know what kinds of arrays are using that.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj!
I have modified my post with a working example of my minimal version. The only problem that I am facing is in the last line of if main, that is where I am taking tanh. Kindly see, I have made the code much simple and easy to read.

Comment: Thanks for editing your code, yes the z_g is supposed to be a matrix that contains single numbers however theta_g is a matrix of dimension similar to z_g, but the individual elements of theta_g are not just numbers but lists of varying length as you have shown above, i.e (1331,),....(343,) etc

Comment: I wish to be able to take inverse of z_g later down my code.

Comment: For an inverse a numeric `z_g` is a must.

Answer (score 0):

You set type of array's elements to `dtype=np.ndarray`. Replace type to, let say, `dtype=np.float64` or any numeric type.